# how do I write this query in linq ( c# )?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, having

```
Select * from table
where Numero_Operacion in 
(
Select Numero_Operacion from table
group by Numero_Operacion
having count(Numero_Operacion)>1
)
```

THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be something like this

```
<Table>.GroupBy(x => x.Numero_Operacion)
       .Where(x => x.Count() > 1)
       .SelectMany(x => x)
```

Comment: thanks for you answer, and the same query how i can write as Lambda expression?

Comment: Lambda expression is just anonimous function - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397687.aspx it's `x => x.Count() > 1` in my code, for example